# Depth contour line using bathymetry

Tags: arcmap, contour, bathymetry

I am a very basic ArcMap user.loaded an ocean color .nc map in ArcMap, (the units of the map are surface phytoplankton chlorophyll mg m-3) on which i overlaid graduated symbols of some of my data. The map is of the waters around the Korean peninsula. Now the reviewer of the paper wants the bathymetric contours around the Korean peninsula. maybe just 1-2 contours. I think I need to download a map of bathymetry and then use Arcmap to make these contours but I dont know how to.

Comment: Can give more info and have just one question to answer please?

Comment: Hi yes of course. I loaded an ocean color .nc map in ArcMap, (the units of the map are surface phytoplankton chlorophyll mg m-3) on which i overlaid graduated symbols of some of my data. The map is of the waters  around the Korean peninsula. Now the reviewer of the paper wants the bathymetric contours around the Korean peninsula. maybe just 1-2 contours. I think I need to download a map of bathymetry and then use Arcmap to make these contours but I dont know how to. Thanks